# Need to cleanup Efivars, but how?

Tags: boot, usb, uefi

I have rebooted my Acer Aspire CloudBook with multiple versions of Linux, Windows 10 and Chrome OS.  Keep going back and forth because all have problems.  Now I can only boot Linux Mint, nothing from USB.  Reason efi partition is full.  Efivars contains 96 items (/sys/firmware/efi/efivars).
How do I reset efi partition without bricking system?

Comment: While at that, could you try http://en.altlinux.org/starterkits there?  I've implemented UEFI support there so sort of intereset in corner cases.

Answer (score 2):

You may have two mostly separate issues:

- a number of obsolete boot variables in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`
- an EFI System Partition (ESP for short) filled up with obsolete bootloaders.

To clean up obsolete EFI boot variables in a controlled manner, use the `efibootmgr` command.

First use `sudo efibootmgr -v` to list all the boot variables and their contents, and identify the ones you don't need. The boot items are identified by `BootXXXX` where XXXX are hexadecimal digits. See the `BootCurrent` variable to identify the boot item your system is currently booted up on.

Then, use `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` to delete the boot items you no longer need.

---

The ESP may be already mounted at `/boot/efi` or `/boot` or perhaps it's unmounted - different distributions handle ESP differently. If you have multiple ESPs, you'll be able to identify it by its *partition UUID*. When you run `sudo efibootmgr -v`, each partition entry will include a long hexadecimal string, known as UUID (or alternatively GUID). With `sudo blkid`, or `lsblk -o +PARTUUID`, you can list the UUIDs of your partitions and find the ESP that matches the UUID in your boot entry.

Mount it if it's not already mounted, then access it as a regular filesystem and clean up any outdated bootloaders.

The ESP has a standardized directory layout: at the top level of the ESP, there should be a directory named `EFI` and below it, each OS vendor can create their own directory to put their bootloader/boot manager into. Windows' boot stuff is within the `Microsoft` sub-directory, each Linux distribution usually has a directory matching their names, and so on. Just delete the directories of the OSs you no longer have installed.

Answer (score 0):

EFI System is just a file system. You have to decide what data is important to you there.

Efivars contains variables used by UEFI and stored in NVRam (probably an  EEPROM) but 96 items isn't an unusually large amount.

You need to inspect the EFI System partition and decide what files are important. Chances are you just have many different distributions boot loaders in there. conventionally each distributions name will be a subdirectory of the ESP and you can delete these subfolders if the distribution is no longer in use.

If you're using EFI-Stub then copys of the kernel would likely be in the ESP maybe you have many old kernel versions. If you're using a boot loader like rEFInd or GRUB it will store some of its resource files in the ESP but usually only the ones it really needs.

You could also just have a really small ESP (sub-50mb) and so normal bootloaders and resources are just filling it.